# How increment a number on a select

Tags: sql

I have this query to retrieve some information from a table:

```
declare @incrementvalue int
set @incrementvalue = 1

select 
    JobName, max(JobTicketField) + @incrementvalue as ID 
from 
    ServiceUsage_T
where 
    JobName = 'Doc1'
group by 
    JobName
```

This works fine if the column `JobTicketField` has some values, i.e Job1, the return are Job2, but if the entry is new, i.e. Job 3 no increment is done.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Tag the correct DB please

Comment: is it MySql or MS SQL?

Answer (score 3):

I assume `JobTicketField` is an int?  If not, adding 1 wouldn't increment as you described.  If so, then I think you are looking for `coalesce`:

```
select JobName, 
     coalesce(max(JobTicketField),0) + 1 as ID 
from ServiceUsage_T 
Where JobName = 'Doc1' 
group by JobName
```

This will return 0 if `JobTicketField` is `null` and then add 1 to it.  Not seeing a use for the `incrementvalue` variable.

Comment: hi sgeddes,thanks by your prompt help. the field are nvarchar, so if the record are the first one the column JobTicketField  remains empty, next time are filled with 1 and so on. carlos

Comment: Hi sgeddes, with your query I can add a new value when the job name are set in jobname row, if the job name are new the row value aren't increased. this is part of the table

Comment: UsageEnd Cardinality JobName JobTicketField
2018-06-16 22:13:58.000 1 Teste21.pdf 6
2018-06-15 00:54:35.000 1 Teste21.pdf 5
2018-06-15 00:51:14.000 1 Teste21.pdf 4
2018-06-15 00:40:39.000 1 Teste21.pdf 3
2018-06-15 00:39:29.000 1 Teste21.pdf 2
2018-06-15 00:36:43.000 1 Teste21.pdf 1
2018-06-14 21:13:19.000 1 Teste.pdf 7